# jEasyUI does not render when the result is more than 30 items

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery-easyui

Please help me to debug the codes below. It was a simple search function that I am trying to display the result via `jEasyui`data grid. It works if the result of the search is bellow 30 items. The problem is, if the query result has more than 30 match, the json file is generated in full but the data grid does not render.

```
<?php
$ip =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$DBresult = $ip."DBtoJson.json";
unlink($DBresult);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



$cat = $_POST['v1'];
$sch = $_POST['v2'];


$username="root";
$password="********";
$database="dbfldp";
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
// $query="SELECT * FROM supportticket ORDER BY support_ticket_number ASC";
$query="SELECT * FROM supportticket WHERE ".$cat." REGEXP '".$sch."' ORDER BY support_ticket_number ASC";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();

$DBresult = $ip."DBtoJson.json";
$fh = fopen($DBresult,'w') or die ("can't open file");

$stringdata = ' {"total":"'.$num.'","rows":[ ';
fwrite($fh, $stringdata);

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"support_ticket_number");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"date_filed");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"time_filed");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"duration");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"department");
$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"markers_error_tag");
$f8=mysql_result($result,$i,"venue");
$f9=mysql_result($result,$i,"racedate");
$f10=mysql_result($result,$i,"racenumber");
$f11=mysql_result($result,$i,"activities_before_occurance");
$f12=mysql_result($result,$i,"running_programs");
$f13=mysql_result($result,$i,"problem_encountered");
$f14=mysql_result($result,$i,"encountered_before");
$f15=mysql_result($result,$i,"support_person_tag");
$f16=mysql_result($result,$i,"support_comment");
$f17=mysql_result($result,$i,"solution");
$f18=mysql_result($result,$i,"resolved");
$f19=mysql_result($result,$i,"watchlist");
if($i<($num - 1)){$comma=",";}
if($i>=($num - 1)){$comma="";}
$stringdata = '
{
"ticketno":"'.$f1.'",
"datefiled":"'.$f2.'",
"timefiled":"'.$f3.'",
"duration":"'.$f4.'",
"name":"'.$f5.'",
"department":"'.$f6.'",
"reportedas":"'.$f7.'",
"racevenue":"'.$f8.'",
"racedate":"'.$f9.'",
"racenumber":"'.$f10.'",
"experiencedwhile":"'.$f11.'",
"runningapps":"'.$f12.'",
"pencountered":"'.$f13.'",
"historical":"'.$f14.'",
"findings":"'.$f15.'",
"supportcomment":"'.$f16.'",
"actioncaken":"'.$f17.'",
"resolved":"'.$f18.'",
"watchlist":"'.$f19.'"
}'.$comma.'
';
fwrite($fh, $stringdata);
$i++;
}

$stringdata = ' ]}';
fwrite ($fh, $stringdata);
fclose($fh);
if (file_exists($DBresult)) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Error DB Entries</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-easyui-1.3.1/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-easyui-1.3.1/themes/icon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-easyui-1.3.1/demo/demo.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-easyui-1.3.1/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-easyui-1.3.1/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>


<script>


    $(function(){
        $('#tt').datagrid({
            url: '<?php echo $DBresult; ?>',
            title: 'Error Reports',
            autoRowHeight: false,
            fitColumns: true,
            width: 'auto',
            rownumbers: true,
            columns:[[
                {field:'ticketno',title:'Ticket Number',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'datefiled',title:'Date Filed',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'timefiled',title:'Time Filed',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'duration',title:'Duration',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'name',title:'Name',align:'center', sortable:'true', hidden: 'true'},
                {field:'department',title:'Department',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'reportedas',title:'Reported as:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'racevenue',title:'Race Venue',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'racedate',title:'Race Date',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'racenumber',title:'R.no#',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'experiencedwhile',title:'Experienced while marker is:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'runningapps',title:'Running Apps:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'pencountered',title:'Problem Encountered:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'historical',title:'With History?:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'findings',title:'Findings:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'supportcomment',title:'Support Comment',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'actioncaken',title:'Action Taken',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'resolved',title:'Resolved?',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'watchlist',title:'Watchlist?',align:'center', sortable:'true'}
            ]],
            onHeaderContextMenu: function(e, field){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (!$('#tmenu').length){
                    createColumnMenu();
                }
                $('#tmenu').menu('show', {
                    left:e.pageX,
                    top:e.pageY
                });
            }
        });
    });
    function createColumnMenu(){
        var tmenu = $('<div id="tmenu" style="width:100px;"></div>').appendTo('body');
        var fields = $('#tt').datagrid('getColumnFields');
        for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
            $('<div iconCls="icon-ok"/>').html(fields[i]).appendTo(tmenu);
        }
        tmenu.menu({
            onClick: function(item){
                if (item.iconCls=='icon-ok'){
                    $('#tt').datagrid('hideColumn', item.text);
                    tmenu.menu('setIcon', {
                        target: item.target,
                        iconCls: 'icon-empty'
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#tt').datagrid('showColumn', item.text);
                    tmenu.menu('setIcon', {
                        target: item.target,
                        iconCls: 'icon-ok'
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="jho" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="v1">
<select class="easyui-combobox" name="v1" style="width:175px;"> 
    <option value="*">Select A Search Category</option> 
    <option value="support_ticket_number">Ticket Number</option> 
    <option value="date_filed">Date Filed</option> 
    <option value="time_filed">Time Filed</option>
    <option value="duration">Duration</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="department">Department</option>
    <option value="markers_error_tag">Reported As:</option>
    <option value="venue">Venue</option>
    <option value="racedate">Race Date</option>
    <option value="racenumber">Race Number</option>
    <option value="activities_before_occurance">Occured while:</option>
    <option value="running_programs">Running Apps</option>
    <option value="problem_encountered">Problem Encountered</option>
    <option value="encountered_before">With History?</option>
    <option value="support_person_tag">Findings:</option>
    <option value="support_comment">Support Comment</option>
    <option value="solution">Action Taken</option>
    <option value="resolved">Resolved?</option>
    <option value="watchlist">Watchlist?</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="v2">
<input type="submit" value="Search" name='submit'>
</form>


<div class="demo-info" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <div class="demo-tip icon-tip"></div>
    <div>Right click the header of datagrid to show context menu.</div>
</div>  
<table id="tt"></table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
} 
else
{?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Error DB Entries</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-easyui-1.3.1/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-easyui-1.3.1/themes/icon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-easyui-1.3.1/demo/demo.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-easyui-1.3.1/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-easyui-1.3.1/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#tt').datagrid({
            url: '<?php echo $ip."DBtoJson.json"; ?>',
            title: 'Error Reports',
            width: 'auto',
            fitColumns: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            singleSelect: true,
            autoRowHeight: false,
            columns:[[
                {field:'ticketno',title:'Ticket Number',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'datefiled',title:'Date Filed',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'timefiled',title:'Time Filed',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'duration',title:'Duration',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'name',title:'Name',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'department',title:'Department',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'reportedas',title:'Reported as:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'racevenue',title:'Race Venue',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'racedate',title:'Race Date',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'racenumber',title:'R.no#',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'experiencedwhile',title:'Experienced while marker is:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'runningapps',title:'Running Apps:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'pencountered',title:'Problem Encountered:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'historical',title:'With History?:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'findings',title:'Findings:',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'supportcomment',title:'Support Comment',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'actioncaken',title:'Action Taken',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'resolved',title:'Resolved?',align:'center', sortable:'true'},
                {field:'watchlist',title:'Watchlist?',align:'center', sortable:'true'}
            ]],
            onHeaderContextMenu: function(e, field){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (!$('#tmenu').length){
                    createColumnMenu();
                }
                $('#tmenu').menu('show', {
                    left:e.pageX,
                    top:e.pageY
                });
            }
        });
    });
    function createColumnMenu(){
        var tmenu = $('<div id="tmenu" style="width:100px;"></div>').appendTo('body');
        var fields = $('#tt').datagrid('getColumnFields');
        for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
            $('<div iconCls="icon-ok"/>').html(fields[i]).appendTo(tmenu);
        }
        tmenu.menu({
            onClick: function(item){
                if (item.iconCls=='icon-ok'){
                    $('#tt').datagrid('hideColumn', item.text);
                    tmenu.menu('setIcon', {
                        target: item.target,
                        iconCls: 'icon-empty'
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#tt').datagrid('showColumn', item.text);
                    tmenu.menu('setIcon', {
                        target: item.target,
                        iconCls: 'icon-ok'
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

          function changeP(pos){  
        $('#tt').datagrid('loadData',[]);  
        $('#tt').datagrid({pagePosition:pos});  
    }  
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="jho" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="v1">
<select class="easyui-combobox" name="v1" style="width:175px;">
    <option value="*">Select A Search Category</option>
    <option value="support_ticket_number">Ticket Number</option> 
    <option value="date_filed">Date Filed</option> 
    <option value="time_filed">Time Filed</option>
    <option value="duration">Duration</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="department">Department</option>
    <option value="markers_error_tag">Reported As:</option>
    <option value="venue">Venue</option>
    <option value="racedate">Race Date</option>
    <option value="racenumber">Race Number</option>
    <option value="activities_before_occurance">Occured while:</option>
    <option value="running_programs">Running Apps</option>
    <option value="problem_encountered">Problem Encountered</option>
    <option value="encountered_before">With History?</option>
    <option value="support_person_tag">Findings:</option>
    <option value="support_comment">Support Comment</option>
    <option value="solution">Action Taken</option>
    <option value="resolved">Resolved?</option>
    <option value="watchlist">Watchlist?</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="v2">
<input type="submit" value="Search" name='submit'>
</form>

<div class="demo-info" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <div class="demo-tip icon-tip"></div>
    <div>Right click the header of datagrid to Change column Visibility.</div>
</div>   
<table id="tt"></table>
</body>
</html>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting in pagination:

`$('#tt').datagrid({`
`url: '<?php echo $DBresult; ?>',`
`title: 'Error Reports',`
`...`
`pagination:true,`
 
`pageSize:50,`
`...`